# ¿Cómo lleno una celda vacía en un Dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

Tengo un Dataframe en el cual tengo variables como "Nombre" "Sexo", "País" etc). El caso es que en la fila 180 tengo el dato de "Fulanito" pero en país su dato está vació, por lo que me gustaría rellenarlo con "México". Hasta el momento he intentado lo siguiente

```
df %>% transform(Pais = case_when(Pais == NA~"Mexico")) %>% View()

df %>%  filter(Nombre == "Fulanito") %>% 
  df$Pais <- "México"
```

Pero ninguno me ha funcionado, también he intentado con `replace_na` pero no me sale. He hecho variaciones usando NA o is.na(Pais) pero no me funciona.
Ya busque mucho pero casi todos los ejemplos reemplazarían a todos los NA con "México" y yo solo quiero reemplazar uno en especifico. Porque de los otros datos NA no se si sean de México.

Comment: Prueba `df <- df %>% mutate(Pais = if_else(is.na(Pais), "Mexico", Pais))` ello debe rellenar todos los NA con México.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu primer intento, el problema es la comparación que haces con el valor `NA`, ocurre que la función de igualdad `==` (y en muchas otras también) cuando hay involucrados valores `NA` siempre el retorno es `NA`. Para validar si un valor es `NA` debes usar la función `is.na()`, que si devuelve un valor lógico:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(Pais = case_when(is.na(Pais) ~ "Mexico", 
                          TRUE ~ Pais))
```

En el caso que uses el `case_when()` deberías igualmente agregar la condición contraria al `NA` para completar el resto de las variables que si tienen país, sino como ya te han sugerido es más directo usar el `if_else()`:

```
df %>% 
   mutate(Pais = if_else(is.na(Pais), "Mexico", Pais))
```

En tu segundo intento, entiendo la idea, pero tienes un problema conceptual, las funciones de `dplyr` no modifican el `data.frame` original, siempre generan una nueva copia, a menos claro que vuelvas asignar el resultado al objeto original, pero en el medio estás haciendo un filtro, con lo cual tampoco llegarías a resolver lo que quieres, además estas combinando funciones y objetos de una manera inválida.

Creo que lo que buscas en tu segundo intento es más bien algo que es natural en R base, que es la modificación "in place" de los objetos, algo como esto

```
df$Pais[df$Nombre == "Fulanito"] <- "Mexico"
```

Comment: Funcionó a la perfección y me aclaraste muchas dudas. Muchas gracias.